# How adjust bootstrap carousel height?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel, saas

This is my website:https://pcshiraz.ir

My carousel image height is not responsive, I can not find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can add this **Stylesheet** i've tried in your website with inspect element it's **worked**!

```
/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .carousel-inner {
    height: 400px;
}

.carousel-item, .carousel-item img {
    height: 400px;
  width:100%;
}

} 

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-inner {
    height: 160px;
}

.carousel-item, .carousel-item img {
    height: 160px;
  width:100%
}
}
```

**Here is Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle the problem with carousel-item active . You can try col-md-6 or col-sm-12
instead of carousel-item active. In this way height will be autosized.

Comment: Try to deepen the answer, include more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
.carousel {
   min-height: auto;
}
```

or try using

```
.carousel {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using viewheight,

```
.carousel{
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Viewheight takes % of screen view. 50vh means it will take up 50% of your display. 100vh will take up 100% of your display.

Answer (score 0):

Just add width: 100% on your slide `<img />` tag. If you are using bootstrap use w-100 class or smth. But be aware that SEO will kick your ass for shrinking images like that, you might want to use several images and show them dependent on screen size.